# Получить массив на стороне сервера PHP из JSON

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать.

```
javascript :
- - - - - - - - - - - - -
var j ='{"1":"xxx", "2":"yyy"}';


отправляю на сервер :
- - - - - - - - - - - - -
...
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", serv, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send("text="+j);
...


php :
- - - - - - - - - - - - -
$data=$_POST['text'];
$d = json_decode($data);


получаю :
- - - - - - - - - - - - -
echo $d->{'1'}; // xxx 
echo $d->{'2'}; // yyy
```

Нужно на стороне сервера получать из этой строки_json еще и такой массив :

```
$m = [['тест 1','a'],['тест 2','d'],['тест 3','a']];
```

Чтобы можно было с этим массивом работать дальше :

```
foreach ($m as $key => $value) {

     if($m[$key][0]==='тест 2') {
         //...
         break;
     }
}
```

Не получается правильно сформировать json_строку и вынуть массив на стороне php.
Делал по разному, например, так :

```
j ='{"1":"xxx", "2":"yyy", "j":{"тест 1":"a","тест 2":"d","тест 3":"a"}}';
```

На стороне сервера добавлял в json_decode *tru*, чтобы работать с массивом данных,
но вынуть такой массив, как показал выше, не получилось. Спасибо.

```
* * * * to Visman * * * *

var m = [['тест 1','a'],['тест 2','d'],['тест 3','a']];

var str = JSON.stringify(m); // str = [["тест 1","a"],["тест 2","d"],["тест 3","a"]];

Дальше :

var j ='{"1":"xxx", "2":"yyy", "m":'+str+'}';
```

как вынуть массив на стороне php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На стороне javascript преобразуйте объект, который вы хотите передать на сервер, в строку с помощью [функции](https://learn.javascript.ru/json#%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-json-stringify) `JSON.stringify(value, replacer, space)`. Пример:

```
var event = {
  title: "Конференция",
  date: "сегодня"
};

var str = JSON.stringify(event);
```

**UPD**
На счет доступа к элементам вложенного массива, как тут:

> j ='{"1":"xxx", "2":"yyy", "j":{"тест 1":"a","тест 2":"d","тест 3":"a"}}';

Вот пример

```
<?php
$str = '{"1":"xxx","2":"yyy","j":{"test 1":"a","test 2":"d","test 3":"a"}}';
$arr = json_decode($str, true);
foreach ($arr['j'] as $key => $value)
{
 echo $key.' --> '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

**UPD2**
Обращение к элементу внутри вложенного ассоциативного массива по его номеру можно сделать так

```
echo ($arr['j'][array_keys($arr['j'])[1]]); // выдаст значение второго элемента (нумерация с 0 идет)
```

P.S. Хотя это извращение ;) Ключи вам известны должны быть.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, не получается вынуть массив ...

Comment: @Alex, в обновлении ответа я показал пример доступа к вложенному массиву.

Comment: спасибо за пример, в цикле $key и $value перебирает, вот только вне цикла я могу вывести, например, echo $d['2'] - получу : yyy, а как получить : test 2, или d. Подскажите, плиз. echo $d['j'] - пишет array, это понятно, как по элементам вложенного пройтись без цикла?

Comment: @Alex, `$d['j']['test 2']`

Comment: так я не знаю заранее этот 'test 2', по номеру можно ?

Comment: да, я, походу, торможу - возьму паузу...

Comment: @Alex, читайте второе обновление поста.

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо, разобрался, очень помогли. Удачи.